# What the performance of Festival TTS vs FreeTTS on windows platforms?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, festival, freetts

9 hours ago I had the wonderful idea to build up from scratch Festival TTS on Windows.

In the meanwhile, and in less than 30 minutes, I build up the same source code on Linux, but only because tons of development tools were already installed :D

Also this morning I downloaded FreeTTS. I started a simple testing project in less of 10 minutes, thanks to the Java power :D. Unfortunately FreeTTS does not provide immediate support for international mbrola languages, so this morning I thinked "it needs too much work"...

Backing to Festival TTS on Windows, after many obstacles, and tons of wrong downloads, CYGWIN before, then "make" and other exotic C++ tools "forgotten" in the installation of CYGWIN, then Visual Studio 2008, then Windows Platform SDK 2008, but it lacks of System.h, so just now I am downloading Windows Server Platform SDK 2003, etc...

So now, as I am yet here without having compiled a single line of damned C-- code, my question is:

at least Festival TTS is a good choice on Windows for Java development?

Answer (score 3):

Festival port to Windows is here:
http://e-guidedog.sourceforge.net/download.php
(includes English voice),
another one (more compact, with Russian voice support) is at berlios.de:

Try yourself, I've tried Russian cluster units voice - speaks fine, though loads the processor - Linux version seems to speak smoother on the same PC.

Answer (score 0):

Festival on Windows is tough.  I've been there.  You might be better off working your solution in Linux and seeing if you can cross-compile to Windows.  I know it sounds hard, but it might actually be easier.